# Program exits before executing rest of the program

Tags: c++, cout, activity-finish

I am trying to create a students program but it stops after I put the 4th name, it doesn't allow me to put the grades neither shows the list at the end...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string name[4];
    double g1[4],g2[4],avg[4];
    int cont;
    for(cont=1;cont<=4;cont++)
    {
        cout<<"STUDENT "<<cont<<"\n";
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>name[cont];
        cout<<"First Grade: ";
        cin>>g1[cont];
        cout<<"Second Grade: ";
        cin>>g2[cont];
        avg[cont]=(g1[cont]+g2[cont])/2;
    }
    cout<<"STUDENTS LIST"<<"\n";
    cout<<"--------------"<<"\n";
    for(cont=1;cont<=4;cont++)
    {
        cout<<name[cont]<<" "<<avg[cont]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `cont < 4` instead of `<=`

Comment: suggestion: aggregate the data in the four arrays into one array of a structure.

Comment: BTW, array indices in C++ start at 0.  When `cont` is 4, you are accessing `g1[4]`, which is actually the 5th element of the array, which is beyond the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two loops `for(cont=1;cont<=4;cont++)` is wrong because you can only use indice `0, 1, 2, 3` for 4-element arrays.

You should use `for(cont=0;cont<4;cont++)` instead and change `cout<<"STUDENT "<<cont<<"\n";` to `cout<<"STUDENT "<<(cont+1)<<"\n";`.

Another option is to add one more elements to each arrays. First elements of the arrays won't be used then, but this may contribute for readability for you.

Answer (score 6):

`string name[4];` is an array with 4 elements. Valid indices are 0,1,2 and 3. Your loops skips the first element and accesses the array out-of-bounds on the last iteraton. That causes undefined behavior. Anything could happen.